# image corrupted when print base64 encripted image using php

Tags: php, image, base64

I'm encrypting imagea into base64 then storing them in the database. I then print the images using PHP, but sometimes I get a corrupted image. If I put the same code in an HTML file, or if I refresh the page many times, then it works.

**This is my corrupted image:**

[image: Corrupted Image]

**My HTML looks like this:**

```
<img src="data:image/png;_encrypteddata_" />
```

*NOTE: `_encrypteddata_` is my encrypted image (I cannot post that huge data here)*

It works fine, but sometimes it shows a continuously corrupted image with the same data. Is it having problem with browser or base64?

I'm using `image/png` for all the icons. Would that cause any problems?

Comment: Looks more like a 404 not found to me. When you inspect the DOM, what is the URL to the image? When you enter that URL in the browser, does the image load?

Comment: url of the image is present with the exact data if i copy that `<img>` whole data put into another file it works

Comment: Why are you "encrypting"? Or do you mean encoding?  It shouldn't be huge either.  A few hundred bytes for an image that small.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically `base64` get much memory for storing encrypted data especially images so whenever you get that little bit huge data from database it takes some times to be loaded . sometimes browser does not wait much time to decrypt so you could see corrupted images.

You better to store your images in the local file system rather than storing into the database. it will speed up your process.

use this code for store your data into local file system

```
function get_image($image_url, $localPathToStore)
{
    echo $url . "<br>" . $saveto;
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
    $raw = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    if (file_exists($saveto)) {
        unlink($saveto);
    }
    $fp = fopen($saveto, 'x');
    fwrite($fp, $raw);
    fclose($fp);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's coming from the browser.

NB :Retreiving image data from the database on every page load can be slow.

Try writing an image file on your filesystem with the data and link to this file in your HTML. It will be faster and more robust.

Answer (score -2):

I got this solution

```
<img src='data:image/;base64,_encrypteddata_'/>
```

From http://www.kingpabel.com/php-base64_encode/